Powershell Pivot Tables Slicers not linked even though using same data source
Using powershell I have created multiple pivot tables in the same Excel worksheet using the same table at the Data Source.
I then open the excel file and add a slicer to one of these Pivot Tables and then try to  link this slicer to the other pivot tables.
I do not see the other pivot tables listed in the "Report Connections" of the slicer.
I have confirmed the Data Source of all the pivot tables are the same table, "CleanDataTable"
this "CleanDataTable" is in a seperate sheet than the pivot tables
When I go to the "CleanDataTable" and manually create a few pivot tables and add slicers to them I can see all the manually created pivot tables AND one of my powershell created pivot tables in the "Report Connections" of the new slicers.
All of my powershell pivot tables are being created the same way, using the ImportExcel Module, with just different values for the PivotRows and Address
Add-PivotTable -Address $Address -SourceWorkSheet $Excel."Clean Data" -PivotRows $pivotRows -PivotData @{"Effort"="Sum"} -PassThru -PivotTableName $pivotName


You might want to ask the author of ImportExcel. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/issues
